# Modal Segue to Show(Push) Segue LargeTitle Navigation not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have my main UIViewController that is presenting my first UITableViewController Modally, then i'm trying to use Show(Push) segue to get to my second UITableViewController but in my second UITableViewController the navigation bar is not showing large title. My first UITableViewController shows the large title nav fine but when i click to go to my second UITableViewController (with show segue) it doesn't show large title. I have LargeTitle set to always for both of the UITableViewControllers but for some reason the second one won't show large title

Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be presenting a `UINavigationController` that has your first `UITableViewController` as the `rootViewController`.

Then the following should work:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```